# Proving that the entropy is zero given conditional entropies

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Let's suppose we have 4 random variables $X,Y,Z$ and $T$ and that the following equations hold about the entropy: 
$$H(T|X)=H(T)$$
$$H(T|X,Y)=0$$
$$H(T|Y)=H(T)$$
$$H(Y|Z)=0$$
$$H(T|Z)=0$$

Also, the following statements are easy to prove and hold:
$$H(T|X,Y,Z)=I(Z;T|X,Y)=0$$
$$I(X;T|Y,Z)=I(Y;T|X,Z)=0$$
$$H(Y|X,Z,T)=I(X;Y|Z,T)=0$$
$$H(T|X,Z)=0$$
$$H(T|Y,Z)=0$$

Now, I want to prove that:
$$H(T)=0$$

I have tried many different things, but I got nothing. Now, I am thinking if there is a way to decompose the entropy like
\begin{eqnarray*}
H(T)&=&\sum\limits_tp_T(t)\log_2p_T(t)\\
&=&\sum\limits_t\Big\{\sum\limits_{x,y,z}p_{TXYZ}(t,x,y,z)\log_2p_{TXYZ}(t,x,y,z)\Big\}\\
&=&\sum\limits_t\Big\{\sum\limits_{x,y,z}p_{TXYZ}(t|x,y,z)p_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\log_2\big\{p_{T|XYZ}(t|x,y,z)p_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\big\}\Big\}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I don't think that $H(T)=0$ is necessarily true under those conditions. Can I ask what is the source of this question, or why you think $H(T)=0$ must hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, I want to prove that: $H(T)=0$

You cannot prove that because it's not true. Counterexample:

Let $X,Y$ be iid fair Bernoulli $(p=1/2)$, let $T= X \oplus Y$ (XOR, or sum in modulus 2). Then $T$ is independent from $X$ and from $Y$ (each taken alone), but it's a deterministic function of the pair $X,Y$. Hence the first three equations, hold. But $H(T)=1$

The last two equations involve an extra variable $Z$, it's easy to construct an example such that $Z$ determines the values of $X$ and $Y$ (and hence $Z$), but still $X$ and $Y$ are iid. Say, $Z$ uniform on $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $X=Z \mod 2$ , $Y=\lfloor Z/2\rfloor $